# Shop categories as search results from attributes table

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, e-commerce

Is it normal to create shop categories not in the categories table but as search results from the attributes table?

What are the pitfalls you might encounter? I never did this before, but now when I working on the website with products that have many different attributes I found that creating many categories not very practical (or maybe I wrong), I tried to search this on web but didn't find info about this db design (or I didn't search properly(?), maybe this approach have some name like programming patterns?).

For example:

```
    Products: Levis[bottoms, jeans, blue], Dockers[bottoms, pants, black], Lee[bottoms, pants, violet]
    Categories:
      Bottoms [query:bottoms]
        Pants [query:pants]
          Violet Pants [query:pants, violet]
        Jeans [query:jeans]

    Products: Abibas[shoes, sport...], SuperBoots[shoes, boots, leather]
    Categories:
      "Shoes"[query:shoes]
        "Leather boots"[query: boots, leather]
        "Sport" [query: sport]
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with a highly normalized design to avoid anomalies and stay DRY. Optimize only if required. Test performance with real world data.

If you're going to use hierarchical or network categories, you should use a database that supports hierarchical ("recursive CTE") queries (i.e. not MySQL).

Use [standard data modeling patterns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example/23831#23831) to save time.

For pure hierarchical categories, have a table like this:

```
create table product_categories (
  category_id int primary key,
  name text not null,
  parent_id int null references categories(category_id),

  unique (name, parent_id)
);
```

and have a foreign key from your products table to the above table.

Answer (score 0):

another way to look at this -- its not always necessary to create separate categories -- sometimes a category is being filtered to make it easier for the customer to find what they want. So in your examples the customer is saying show me only those Boots that are made of Leather, OR show me pants in just the color Violet.

balanced by what your market is -- if people come to your website to buy Leather Boots then having that be its own category would make sense. thats a very specific destination category that could also have lots of sub-categories.

versus violet colored pants -- maybe that is a destination category somewhere :-) 
but most likely it would be a search filter that would be applied to a category.

another consideration for categories is they are extremely important for SEO so you want to keep your core category structure consistent so you can get ranked appropriately.